# Canvas: Rectangles -- Snap to grid / Snap to objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I managed to manipulate Fabric.js to add a snap and scale to grid functionality by:

```
var grid = 100;
//Snap to Grid
canvas.on('object:moving', function (options) {
    options.target.set({
        left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
        top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
    });
});
canvas.on('object:scaling', function (options) {
    options.target.set({
        left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
        top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
    });
});
```

Now I want to add snap to objects functionality. My idea was to check intersection of two objects and then lock somehow the movement. I know its not the best attempt, but at least it snaps to it, but does not allow to move the object away anymore. And: right now it is not implemented well. See: http://jsfiddle.net/gcollect/y9kyq/

I have three issues:

1. The "snap" doesn't work well, because the object left attribute depends on the pointer somehow. Replication by dragging object and watching my controls output. For example when moving the red rectangle to position left:62, the rectangle isn't intersected with the blue rectangle and can still moved away. How can I reload the actual left value of the rectangle. Because of my snap to grid lines, it is at left:100 and not at left:62.
2. Any idea how I can add a snap to object functionality? And prohibit intersection?
3. How can I check this for n objects and not only for two?

Thanks for your comments.

PS:
The jsfiddle example doesn't show the scale to grid functionality, because it needed Fabric.js manipulation in line: 11100

```
var distroundedforgrid = Math.round(dist/100)*100;      
      transform.newScaleX = Math.round((transform.original.scaleX * distroundedforgrid / lastDist)*10)/10;
      transform.newScaleY = Math.round((transform.original.scaleY * distroundedforgrid / lastDist)*10)/10;

      target.set('scaleX', transform.newScaleX);
      target.set('scaleY', transform.newScaleY);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately till now, I don't have any progress regarding the snap to objects functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who are still interested in the solution:
I solved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22649022/3207478
See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcollect/FD53A/

Working with `.oCoords.tl .tr .bl. and .br solved it.`

Answer (score 4):

For rescaling based on the grid see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xmysw95b/) JSfiddle

```
function snapScaling(options) {
    var target = options.target;
    var type = canvas.getActiveObject().get('type');
    var corner = target.__corner;
    var w = target.getWidth();
    var h = target.getHeight();
    var snap = {   // Closest snapping points
      top: Math.round(target.top / grid) * grid,
      left: Math.round(target.left / grid) * grid,
      bottom: Math.round((target.top + h) / grid) * grid,
      right: Math.round((target.left + w) / grid) * grid,
    };
    snap.height = snap.top - snap.bottom;
    if(snap.height < 0) {
      snap.height *= - 1;
    }
    snap.width = snap.left - snap.right;
    if(snap.width < 0) {
      snap.width *= - 1;
    }
    switch (corner) {
      case 'mt':
      case 'mb':
          target.top = snap.top;
          target.height = snap.height;
          target.scaleY = 1;
        break;
      case 'ml':
      case 'mr':
        target.left = snap.left;
        target.width = snap.width;
        target.scaleX = 1;
        break;
      case 'tl':
      case 'bl':
      case 'tr':
      case 'br':
        target.top = snap.top;
        target.left = snap.left;

        target.height = snap.height;
        target.width = snap.width;

        target.scaleY = 1;
        target.scaleX = 1;
    }

    if(type == 'ellipse') {
      target.rx = (target.width / 2);
      target.ry = (target.height / 2);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is nice but breaks when the object has been rotated 90 degrees and you try to scale by using on of the top controls (now on the side).

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out to solve the snap to objects on x-axis and will work on a solution for the y-axis. [See JSfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/gcollect/jyd4E/)

I did this by setting a new "left"-value for the active object, when I detect an intersection.

```
        if (options.target.isContainedWithinObject(obj)||options.target.intersectsWithObject(obj)||obj.isContainedWithinObject(options.target)) {

            var distx = ((obj.left + obj.width)/2) - ((options.target.left + options.target.width)/2);
            var disty = ((obj.top + obj.height)/2) - ((options.target.top + options.target.height)/2);                  

            if (distx > 0){
                options.target.left = obj.left - options.target.width;
            } else {
                options.target.left = obj.left + obj.width;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Now I experience some issues after modifying the heights or widths of objects and try to snap them afterwards. The objects still intersect and snap within the objects because of the old values. Do I need to render the objects new?

Comment: is it possible that the fiddle be viewable again pelasE?

Comment: Hi Steve Green,
here is the same example. I still havent managed to solve the problem.
Would be cool if you could help. Problem begins in line 59. Comment in the distx lines to see the false behaviour.
http://jsfiddle.net/gcollect/XCX9A/