# Detect fabric js object edges and avoid overlap

Tags: fabricjs

I have a fabric triangle

```
var fabObj = new fabric.Triangle({
            left: 250,
            top: 250,
            fill: 'white',
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
            name:'triangle',
            borderColor: '#f0000',
            cornerSize: 8,
            transparentCorners: true,  
            hasControls:true,
            lockScalingX:true,
            lockScalingY:true
        });

$scope.canvas.add(fabObj);
$scope.canvas.setActiveObject(fabObj);
$scope.canvas.renderAll();
```

It creates the triangle like following
[image]

I want another triangle to fit on either side but could not overlap each other
[image]

Have tried this code but it only detect corners (square boundary of triangle )
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31153459/3377733

Please refer to this following fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/m0jjc23v/23/

Comment: Can you show problem in jsfiddle ? Have you test with perPixelTargetFind ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m0jjc23v/21/
Yes I have tried  it here but it did not solve the scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric.js is not build to handle such scenarios. It's better to use Matter JS http://brm.io/matter-js/

They do handle all physics properties.